Sponsorship banner causes layout shifting when loading mobile site
When the site first loads, it looks like this, without the sponsorship banner:

After about a second, the banner loads and the page looks like this:

This moves all the content of the page down by almost the height of a question entry, so if a user was in the process of tapping on a particular question or button, that tap now lands on something other than what they meant to click, and they navigate somewhere else entirely.
Would it be possible to adjust the style sheet used during sponsorships so that the title bar loads with the appropriate amount of blank space for the banner from the initial layout state, so that there's not a change in the positions of controls when the sponsored banner loads?

"It's not a bug, it's a feature!" :p

The solution will likely be to add the space for the banner upon the initial page load, so that there won't be the "jump". We'll need to provide a configuration option for this, so that the space is only there when a banner might appear. This work is not yet scheduled so I don't have an estimate for when it might be completed.

Understood — thanks for the update!
